# Pulling emoji URL from .json gives undefined

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

so I am working on a bot, and I have the following code. I am attempting to get a color name from the `args[1]` of the message and use the color name to figure out which emoji link to grab, and have the following code to pull that from the json in the bot -

```js
const store = require(‘./../../items.json’);

// inside module.exports -
const item = args[0];
const col = args[1];

let name = store[item].name;
let price = store[item].price;
let desc = store[item].description;

let emote = store[item].col // trying to grab the emote link from the variable
```

When put into an embed, it returns “undefined” for the emote variable. The below code is the json bit (in this case, the item variable is fish) -

```json
{
   “fish”: {
      “name”: “fish”,
      “price”: “$1”,
      “description”: “<description here>“,

      “white”: “https://<white fish emoji link here>”,
      “pink”: “https://<pink fish emoji link here”
    }
}
```

I have asked in multiple discord servers, and have looked around online for answers.

Comment: Have you logged the variables to see if they are what you think they are?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an if else statement the way you are doing you cant fetch the object values with an variable with your way you can check if col === pink then give emote value x if col === blue give emote value y and so on like so

```
if(col === 'pink'){
let emote = store[item].pink
}
```

**Edit** Use let instead of const

Comment: this logs as "invalid form body," since I am trying to set the emoji url from the items.json  as the thumbnail, however it still does not make it undefined

Comment: can i see the code and the error did u just copy my code?

Comment: it is saying that it has to be in http, https format since it is a thumbnail, however the link is the https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/<emoji ID>.png?v=1 link, so the variable is in https format

Comment: yeah, let me show you the error as of now. I didn't copy your code directly, no

Comment: (node:28255) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.thumbnail.url: Scheme "0" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https').

Comment: "t is saying that it has to be in http, https format" that doesnt make sense it has to be in https in https forat wdym?

Comment: can i get the proper link in "" quotes?

Comment: it is saying, since I am trying to set it as the thumbnail, it has to be in "http, https format." Since it is showing up as undefined, that is why it is giving an error

Comment: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/798262414646181938.png?v=1"

Comment: try to append an https and check like "https://https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/798262414646181938.png?v=1"

Comment: actually I think I am just going to upload the image files to my site and use an await function to fetch them from there, that sounds a bit more time-efficient. Thanks for the help though!